# Perlbrew doesn't list installed versions of Perl

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I've a problem with the original Perl version in Ubuntu 16.04 and i wanted to compile and install a new one.
I've used Perlbrew to create a new Perl 5.18.2 with threads available and another one 5.18.8 for testing purposes.
I can see the directory containing all the downloaded and compiled files in '/home/my_name/perl5/perlbrew' but i
cannot lists the versions available with the 'Perlbrew list' command and consequently i cannot switch to any new version of Perl.

If there's anybody out there who can help me it would be much appreciated.

This issue is driving me crazy

Comment: Stupid question: did you mean `perlbrew list` (in lower case)?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please provide the output of `type perlbrew | head -n 1; printf '%s\n' "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"; \ls -l "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"/perls; perlbrew list`

Comment: There is no Perl 5.18.8 .

Comment: 'perlbrew list' command now is working fine now. Don't know why, i just simpy purge and install againg perlbrew.

Comment: The problem i get now, but i guess it's an off topic here is linked with threads module of installed versions of perl and forks with ubuntu 16.04 one. but i will follow with a new question on this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
perlbrew available --all | grep i
```

or built-in command to list perl installations

```
perlbrew list
```